# Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection

Tags: genymotion

When I start the Virtual Device in Genymotion, it cannot run to the main screen and show this log in the terminal:

```
OpenGL connected to 192.168.56.101:25000

Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections

PING timed out

Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
```

Could anyone solve this issue?

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

From Mark

I have had some success with an earlier version of VirtualBox after stopping my firewall from blocking communications between the AndroVM Player and VirtualBox. However, after updating to the latest version of VirtualBox I started having a similar looking problem again - the VM would start to boot with Hardware Open GL Enabled, it would get to the point where it was trying to communicate with the AndroVM Player, the AndroVM Player would boot, and would get to the point where it was waiting for communications from the VM, but the two would never seems to speak.

As a test I tried pinging the IP address for the Host VM (`192.168.56.101`) - this wasn't successful. I ran IP Config and checked the IP address for the Host Only Adaptor - it was `169.254.x.x`. That's when it hit me - there was no way for there to be any communications between the AndroVM Player and the Host VM. I've managed to resolve this by going in to Virtual Box and in to File -> Preferences -> Network and then clicking on Edit Host-Only Network. Change the IP v4 address to `192.168.56.1`. OK everything and suddenly I could see the Host VM in the AndroVM Player.

I don't know if this would be the same in VirtualBox for other platforms, but it would be worthwhile checking if you are having these kinds of issues.